# http status 500-Error instantiating servlet class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring, apache, http

[image: Directory hierarchy of file]

Above is the directory hierarchy of my program

I am new to spring and learning MVC concepts I have written a program which takes input(Name) into a text box and prints Hello...'name'. Tha following is my directory structure and the various files I have created.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>MVC_HelloWorld</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> 
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- default configuration -->
  <servlet>
   <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>



<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.ap</url-pattern> <!-- this same extension should bbe used in form action -->
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

HelloWorld-servlet.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
<!-- default handler mapping -->
<!--  file should be created under web inf annd it's view resolver file -->

  <!-- handler(Not rqd in case of default handler) -->
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />

  <!-- controller configuration -->
<bean name="/HelloWorld.ap" class="controller.HelloController"> <!-- mapping url pattern to controller class using 'name' -->

<!-- view resolver -->

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
       <property name="prefix" vlaue="/"/> <!-- default location (prefix used foor rqd page locations) -->
       |<property name="sufix" value=".jsp"/> <!-- sufix used forr rqd page extensions -->

</bean>

</bean>

</beans>
```

HelloController.java

```
package controller;

import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

import com.sun.javafx.collections.MappingChange.Map;

public class HelloController implements Controller {

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {

        String name=req.getParameter("name");

        Map m= new HashMap();   // creating output object
           m.put("msg","Hello..."+name);

          ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("success"+m);



        return mav;
    }

}
```

index.jsp

```
<h1> Hello World</h1>

<form action="./hello.ap">

NAME: <input type="text" name="name">
      <input type="Submit" value="Say Hello">
</form>
```

success.jsp

```
${msg}
```

when I am running this code the index.jsp page is running properly bur upon further execution It shows Error 500. what's wrong with the code..?? I am using Eclipse oxygen in that apache 8.5

Answer (score 0):

You configuration in web.xml are wrong.

You are trying to map the dispatch servlet as the controller.
In spring mvc like in other mvc frameworks (struts etc.) there is one major servlet that use to dispatch all requests.

org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet is usually named “dispatcher” and should be mapped to a top level url usually “\”

e.g.

```
  <servlet>
                <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
            </servlet>
  ...  
    <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>
```

And the controller is mapped under this url e.g. HelloWorld

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/HelloWorld");"
public class HelloController implements Controller {}
```

As your initial project is far from the classic vanilla starter Spring MVC project and it looks like you are using a very old Spring version (or spring tutorial). I suggest to start fresh from some online tutorial.

E.g.

http://www.journaldev.com/2433/spring-mvc-tutorial
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/gradle-spring-mvc-web-project-example/

Comment: Sorry but I am not getting the solution you said..could you plz make change in my document so that it will be easy to understand

Comment: I did not offer a solution, just pointed one of the errors you have. Start from a sample project from one of the tutorials.

Comment: You can try to clone one of my samples as well https://github.com/ramanh3/rest-json

Answer (score 0):

Try below edit to web.xml.

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.ap</url-pattern> <!-- this same extension should bbe used in form action -->
</servlet-mapping>
```